# Delete, Free, or Deallocate?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I'm running into a problem where I use too much memory on the stack. I'm using several large arrays that I only need between steps in my code. Basically I need to know how to release the memory used by an array variable that's created as:

```
float arrayName[length][width];
```

Comment: Consider allocating your array dinamically instead of trying to free the array.

Comment: I'd be more concerned with how to more-effectively *allocate* memory first rather than via an automatic variable.

Comment: How much memory does your stack have?  Ubuntu 15.10 (64) defaults to 8 MBytes per thread. And if you have n MBytes, how are you deciding you are are using 'too much'? 50%  90%  somebodies requirement, or perhaps difficult to understand crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To intentionally release some auto storage (items on the 'stack'), you can do the following -  basically you simply limit the scope of your variables

change code from:

```
//...
float arrayName[length][width]; 
// ...
```

change code to:

```
//...
{
    float arrayName[length][width]; 
    // use arrayName here

    //... still in-scope
} // scope limit
// all of arrayName released from stack 

{
    // stack is available for other use, so try
    uint32_t  u32[3][length][width]; 
    // use u32 here


    //... still in-scope
} // scope ended
// all of u32 released from stack 

// better yet, use std::vector or another container
std::vector<uint32_t>  bigArry;
```

NOTE: a vector uses a finite amount of stack (24 bytes on my system), 
regardless of how many elements you put into it!

Comment: On one of my games, I use a "typedef std::vector<Cell_t*> GameBoard_t".  Note the single dimension of this vector, yet the Gamboard is 2 dim.  I simply use a function to compute a gameboard index from row,col coordinates ... "static inline size_t gbIndx(int row, int col, int MAXCol)  { return ((row * MAXCol) + col); }.  Very easy and very fast.  In addition, many accesses to the gameboard do not use row,col and instead simply step through the entire vector,  examples: screenUpdate(), clearGameBoard()

Comment: Between the scope limiting braces of my answer, note that you only need one function or method to enable many KLOC's of code to access the 'big' data store.  (But remember to pass it by reference ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use vectors for things like this.  It is a part of the C++ standard library and is very optimized in most implementations.  The memory taken up by the vector will automatically get released when the vector goes out of scope.  So you will never have to free up the memory yourself.

Another benefit with using a vector is that you do not have to worry about running out of stack space since all the "array" memory taken up by the vector is located on the heap of the program.

For examples http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Other than that if you think your program memory is never going to be enough then you should consider using the disk as another storage mechanism.  Databases work this way.  They store most of their data on disk.

Comment: @Downvoter Could you please leave a comment as to why you downvoted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You won't need any special statements.

The array will be released on function return or exiting the scope if it is local variable having automatic storage duration, or on exiting the program if it is static variable (declared outside functions).

Comment: I think he is talking about the situation of several large stack array within a single function, and he wants to deallocate ones that are not used in the remainder of the function

Answer (score -1):

You may want to allocate the memory on the heap if you are running into a situation where you are running out of memory on the stack.  In this case you'll want to new up the  array.

```
float** my_array = new float* [rowCount];
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
 {
    my_array[i] = new float[columnCount];
 }


// and delete it later
 for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i) 
  {
    delete [] my_array[i];
  }

delete [] my_array;
```

Comment: No, you don't want this. There are `columnCount` possible memory leaks in there. Before thinking how to fix them, observe that Curious already has a simpler suggestion without memory leaks.